# First push nearest value in array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML Code

```
<a class="ytclink" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wB0JY_F3370">
    <img width="100" height="100" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/0GU-sgt3irU/0.jpg">
</a>
<h5 class="ytctitle">
  <a class="ytclink"  href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wB0JY_F3370">Play</a>
</h5>
  <a class="ytclink" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hB0er_F3356">
    <img width="100" height="100" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/0GU-sgt3irU/0.jpg">
  </a>
<h5 class="ytctitle">
  <a class="ytclink"  href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hB0er_F3356">Play</a>
</h5>

<a class="ytclink" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ghhh_F6667">
   <img width="100" height="100" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/0GU-sgt3irU/0.jpg">
</a>
<h5 class="ytctitle">
  <a class="ytclink"  href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ghhh_F6667">Play</a>
</h5>
```

jQuery Code

```
var utubes= [];
$('.ytclink').click(function(){
        $(".ytclink").each(function() {
        var res= $(this).attr('href').split("watch?v=")[1];
        var found = jQuery.inArray(res, utubes);
                if (found >= 0) {               
                } else {
                //Element was not found, add it.
                utubes.push(res);
                }
        //utubes.push(res);
        });
        alert(utubes);
    });
```

My code is working fine so far, but need some changes if i click any a tag , h5 tag so href value push in from start of page, want to push first nearest href value for exmple if click below code

```
<a class="ytclink" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hB0er_F3356"><img src="video.jgp"</a>
<h5 class="ytctitle"><a class="ytclink"  href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hB0er_F3356">Play</a></h5>
```

Then need output like that in alert:

```
   ghhh_F6667,wB0JY_F3370,hB0er_F3356
```

[JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6bC3K/1/)

Comment: And you want alert to show only hB0er_F3356 in this example?

Comment: if i click second a or h5 tag need output like that ghhh_F6667,wB0JY_F3370,hB0er_F3356 and if click third a or h5 tag need output like that wB0JY_F3370,hB0er_F3356,ghhh_F6667

Comment: It might help if you used numbers to say what you want instead of IDs. 1,2,3 for instance.

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/6bC3K/1/

Comment: modified the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6bC3K/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code worked fine for me

```
var utubes= [];
$('.ytclink').click(function(){

       var index1 =  $('.ytclink').index(this);
    index1=parseInt(index1/2);

        var length  = $('.parentDiv  .ytclink').size()/2;
    var i=1;

    while ( index1-i >-1 || index1+i<length){
        if(index1+i<length)
        utubes.push($('.parentDiv > .ytclink').eq(index1 +i).attr('href').split("watch?v=")[1]);
        if(index1-i >-1)
        utubes.push($('.parentDiv > .ytclink').eq( index1 -i ).attr('href').split("watch?v=")[1]);
        i++;
    }

    utubes.push($(this).attr('href').split("watch?v=")[1]);
        alert(utubes);
    });
```

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6bC3K/2/)